# enum is undefined in component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a file named waypoint-edit-action.ts

inside I have the following =>

```
export declare enum WaypointEditActions {
  INIT = 0,
  MOUSE_MOVE = 1,
  ADD_POINT = 2,
  ADD_LAST_POINT = 3,
  CHANGE_TO_EDIT = 4,
  REMOVE_POINT = 5,
  DRAG_POINT = 6,
  DRAG_POINT_FINISH = 7,
  DRAG_SHAPE = 8,
  DRAG_SHAPE_FINISH = 9,
  DONE = 10,
  DISABLE = 11,
  ENABLE = 12,
  DISPOSE = 13,
  SET_EDIT_LABELS_RENDER_CALLBACK = 14,
  UPDATE_EDIT_LABELS = 15,
  SET_MANUALLY = 16,
  TRANSFORM = 17
}
```

I try to use this enum from a component

```
import { WaypointEditActions } from '../models/waypoint-edit-actions';
```

and `WaypointEditActions.INIT`

but it say that INIT is undefined... why ?

Comment: What about the others? Like WaypointEditActions.DISPOSE, is undefined too?

Comment: actually I removed the declare and now it is ok

Answer (score 1):

try to remove `decleare` key word from enum decleration -

```
export enum WaypointEditActions {
     INIT = 0,
     MOUSE_MOVE = 1,
     ADD_POINT = 2,
     ADD_LAST_POINT = 3,
     CHANGE_TO_EDIT = 4,
     REMOVE_POINT = 5,
     DRAG_POINT = 6,
     DRAG_POINT_FINISH = 7,
     DRAG_SHAPE = 8,
     DRAG_SHAPE_FINISH = 9,
     DONE = 10,
     DISABLE = 11,
     ENABLE = 12,
     DISPOSE = 13,
     SET_EDIT_LABELS_RENDER_CALLBACK = 14,
     UPDATE_EDIT_LABELS = 15,
     SET_MANUALLY = 16,
     TRANSFORM = 17
}
```